# why play store displays "no performance data avaliable"?

Tags: android

So, My app has run fine on all 13 devices according to pre launch report of play store, but does gave warning and in the performance section, on device of Samsung Galaxy S3, it says, no performance data is available for this device, any idea, why that can be issue and can play store not let me publish my app because of that warning, 
Screenshots- 
[image: image of device being tested]

[image: image of not showing data]

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Console performance report data requires that the application be installed and used on any device. Detailed information is [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6263332?hl=en)

Are you sure your application is opened in Galaxy S3? I think your application is downloaded Galaxy S3 device but does not opened.

Comment: Oh, that's what issue is, so it got installed but if it did not get opened, then should not there be crash being displayed

Comment: When an application is installed, the number of crash count starts to be displayed directly at zero. But the performance report is displayed as soon as the application is opened. @VaibhavKumar

Comment: oh, I am noobie, thats why i asked

Comment: ah, app got rejected for violating family, while app just opens social app at voice, any advice

Comment: That is so different question and there are so many reasons of that. You can check potential reasons in this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/18517542?hl=en) . If my answer is enough for this question please accept and open another question.